# Named Credentials with Authorization Protocol OAuth 2.0 vs authorization and authentication handled using apex

Tags: rest-api, integration, oauth2, namedcredentials, auth-provider

Could anyone please clarify my doubts. If I use **Authentication Protocol** as **Oauth 2.0** and provide an **Authentication Provider** for the same with required settings and call a rest end point of different org

[image]

then how does the underlying mechanism differs from the below sample code?

[image].

If we do not use named credentials and handle it in apex then we only require to hit token end point of salesforce and the grant_type needs to be specified as passwords. But if we use named credentials with **Authentication Protocol** as **Oauth 2.0**, then we need to specify authorization end point and token end. So does it mean if we use **Authentication Protocol** as **Oauth 2.0** the **grant_type** implicitly becomes **authorization_code**

Comment: Yes, the grant type is the difference. As you correctly surmised, NC will only do authorization code out of the box.

Comment: Thank you @identigral for clarifying.